# How to set 1920x1080 image in 1280*800 android device?

Tags: android

I am try to set dynamic screen resolution for layout.

finding screen resolution using this code.

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        System.out.println("display width:"+width);
        System.out.println("display height:"+height);
```

I have following table of content 
how to display dynamically in layout

left    top width   height

0   0   1080    1920

0   0   1080    1920

0   1260    1057    650

17  962 562 262

I have 4 liner layout 
set dynamically height and width to different resolution android device.
Please help me....

Comment: Set to auto resize your image.

Comment: @suufang not image resolution, set layout height and width